# How to configure HAProxy to access K8S cluser?

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy

I have setup K8S cluster, it is up and running

- 5 control planes
- 8 worker nodes

I have setup HAproxy working OK

- 2 nodes
- 1 virtaul IP

I can access the clustre from a client by using admin.conf file copied from any of the control plane machine.

My question is what I need to do to be able to access the cluster through the Virtaul IP of the HAproxy? What do I need to copy to HAproxy nodes and how to modify the config file?

I did change the endpoint in the config file from control plane to VIP of HAproxy, but looks like the certificates also need to changed as well?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

To add up from the same question you posted in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77607755/how-to-configure-haproxy-to-access-k8s-cluser), here's an example of the HAProxy configuration file:

```
frontend kubernetes
  bind :80
  default_backend kubernetes-api

backend kubernetes-api
  server k8s-api 10.0.0.1:6443
    check inter 2s fall 3 rise 2
    ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
```

The HAProxy frontend listens for connections on port 80 and directs traffic to the `kubernetes-api` backend. The backend points to the Kubernetes API server running on the IP address `10.0.0.1` and port `6443`. The `ca-file` directive specifies the path to the CA certificate file used for SSL verification.

Restart HAProxy to apply your changes then test your configuration by accessing your Kubernetes cluster through the HAProxy frontend.

Here are some resources that might be helpful to you:

[HAProxy Kubernetes Ingress Controller documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/kubernetes-ingress/overview/)

[Blog post on setting up HAProxy for a Kubernetes cluster](https://medium.com/@sujitthombare01/haproxy-smart-way-for-load-balancing-in-kubernetes-c2337f61d90b)